# Changing attributes value in angular2 template

Tags: svg, angular, angular2-directives

I have simple angular2 component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'circle',
  template: `<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" 
      stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
    </svg>`,
})  
export class Circle { }
```

And I would like to dynamic change `fill` attribute using some parameter for component, for example like `<circle color="red"></circle>` and and as result have red circle. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `[...]` syntax with the `attr` prefix for your attribute. See the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'circle',
  template: `<svg height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" 
      stroke-width="3" [attr.fill]="fillAttr" />
    </svg>`,
})  
export class Circle {
  fillAttr:string = 'red';
}
```

If you want to provide an input to the component, use the `@Input` decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'circle',
  (...)
})
export class Circle {
  @Input('color')
  fillAttr:string = 'red';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I pass data to `fillAttr` from circle element attribute?

Comment: You mean when using your component?

Comment: Yes, like `<circle color="red"></circle>`